# How do i make this exit in the command promt if the word "exit" is typed?

Tags: c++

I am having to write a program that asks the user to type a sentence into the command prompt. If the user typed the word "exit" or "Exit" (without quotes and all lower case), then the program should exit. Otherwise, the program should print what the user typed back to the screen and ask the user to type something else. I understand how to get the sentence in, but I do not know how to make the program exit the command prompt. Help please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string data;

    cout << "Type a sentence and press enter."
        "If the word 'exit' is typed, the program will close." << endl;

    getline(cin, data);
    cout << data;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a loop condition

Comment: Looks like a good job for a [do-while loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do).

Comment: Is exiting what you want and cannot do? What happens when the `return 0;` is reached? Is that not what you want? Or is NOT existing what you want, in that case use a loop, as other have commented. Or do you want the command prompt to exit? In that case youmight need to create the command prompt in a way that it closes when your program has ended. that would be a shell question.

Comment: What I want it to do is if the word exit is typed, the command prompt needs to close.

Comment: @Isaiah: That will not be standard C++ and will be OS specific. What OS are you dealing with?

Comment: i'm using visual studio

Comment: If you're running from Visual Studio, just exiting the program will close the window it runs in.

Comment: @Isaiah, since you are using Visual Studio, I have updated my code which is OS independent. Earlier it was for Linux environment.

Comment: you guys rock! I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 3):

You could compare the value receive data with "exit".
If you want just display type back the user data, try this:

```
int main() {
    string data;

    cout << "Type a sentence and press enter."
            "If the word 'exit' is typed, the program will close." << endl;

    getline(cin, data);


    // validate if data is equals to "exit"
    if (data.compare("exit") != 0) {
        cout << data;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you want type back use input while "exit" is typed, try this:

```
int main() {
    string data;

    do {

        cout << "Type a sentence and press enter."
                "If the word 'exit' is typed, the program will close." << endl;

        getline(cin, data);

        // validate if data is not equals to "exit"
        if (data.compare("exit") != 0) {
            // then type back
            cout << data  << endl;
        } else {
            // else interrupt while
            break;
        } 
    // will run while break or return be called
    } while (true);

    // terminate the program
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second example is better handled using a `do/while` loop instead. No need to duplicate the same code twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string data;
    while(true) {

    cout << "Type a sentence and press enter."
        "If the word 'exit' is typed, the program will close." << endl;

    getline(cin, data);
    if ( boost::iequals(data, "exit") ) 
        exit(0);
    else 
        cout << data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd probably be more inclined to `break` than `exit(0)`, but yeah.

Comment: why use `boost::iequals()` instead of `std::string::operator==` or `std::strcmp()` or the like? Not everyone has Boost installed.